# Which area of physics deals with principle of work of BJTs, diodes and other semiconductor elements and which book do you suggest covering this?

Tags: bjt, ttl, physics

Which area of physics deals with principle of work of BJTs, diodes,...?

I'm familiar with equations that describe operation of these elements but I have no idea how they work "internally". I started learning Digital electronics and I'm trying to understand how different TTL implementations of logical gates work but I have hard times in learning this, probably because I learned only equations that describe these elements but I have no idea how they work.

Which book covers this field? I need some introductory book to this field because I'm complete beginner.

EDIT: I would not go in quantum mechanics, I'm not physics student. I'm electrical eng. student. I want to learn principle of working to be able to successfully use these devices as Electrical Engineer.

Comment: This has been asked before, so I would suggest looking\searching for previous questions on this site. Secondly these types of questions are opinion based. A better way would be to get your research skills on and visit the local (or preferably a university) library or do an extensive internet campaign. That being said, the "Art of Electronics" by Winfield and Horowitz is a great book for what your looking for. Please also poke around in the help center and meta and become accustomed with the community. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are really talking about the low-level device physics: Semiconductor Physics. They tend to sit close to quantum mechanics and such. Band diagrams, energy levels, tunneling, are all common.

There are a few good books out there. It is always interesting to look at wikipedia and start form there. Just google around, there are likely many pages dedicated to the field of semiconductor physics and technology.

Comment: Hello, thanks for reply. Please refresh, I edited my question.

Comment: You stated that you already knew what was up with the high level in equations. I assume you meant things like the I/V characteristics of devices. If you want to go into more detail, you need to accept that you are dealing with low level things like band diagrams. What you are saying is "I want to learn how you make cakes but I don't want to deal with any of this flour stuff"

Comment: Hello. Yes, I meant I/V characteristics and equations that describe BJT in different modes of operation. I want to learn everything about BJT internal principle of work that one Electrical Engineer should know. Physicists probably learn more details than Electrical. Eng. but I'm not Physicis student.

Comment: The ones an engineering student should know are those low level things requirering quantum mechanics. How deep you delve is another matter, but you can't understand the workings of a PN junction without understanding electron bands and how they relate to band diagrams, the impact doping has on them, ...

Comment: Ok. I'm ready to learn whatever is needed :)  Because I'm not familiar with this area of science, I need to go from "very beginning". What do you think about "Physics of Semiconductor Devices" by Simon Sze?

Comment: I have that book here, somewhere. It misses some stuff, last time I checked it spends little time on Zener/Avalanche breakdown and could use some more time on short-channel effects. Overall, a decent book, but I haven't read many others so I can't really compare.

Comment: Maybe it is good idea to get few different books and combine them :)  I will google for some other books too

Comment: I found this: Semiconductor Physics And Devices: Basic Principles by Donald A. Neamen. I will probably download few books in pdf and print them all.